# Command for approximating a function in variable limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

[The function](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1WlFhiz5UjwC&pg=PA104&dq=two%20level%20system%20heat%20capacity%20%20statistical%20mechanics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit17LRhf_ZAhVIuY8KHakuBssQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=two%20level%20system%20heat%20capacity%20%20statistical%20mechanics&f=false)

$ f(T) = 1/T^2 Exp(1/T) [Exp(1/T) + 1]^{-2} $

in low $T$ limit is $ f(T)=Exp(-1/T)$

and in high $T$ limit $(T)=1/T^2$.

Is there a command in mathematica to find the the function in low and high $T$ limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code does the trick:

```
limiter=Function[{input,variable,limit},
FullSimplify[TrigToExp[
Simplify[Normal[FullSimplify[
input SeriesData[variable,limit,List[1],0,1,1]
]]]]//.Plus[a_,b_]:>a/;AsymptoticEqual[a+b,a,variable->limit]]
];
```

For example:

```
f[x_] := 1/x^2 Exp[1/x] (Exp[1/x] + 1)^-2;

limiter[f[x], x, 0]
```

> Sech[1/x]/(2 x^2)

```
limiter[f[x], x, Infinity]
```

> 1/(4 x^2)

```
limiter[f[x], x, a]
```

> 1/(2 a^2 (1 + Cosh[1/a]))

The main issue is that we are trying to obtain asymptotic forms around singular points hence naive series command would not work. Above, we use SeriesData command to force a series form, replace $a+b$ with $a$ if both produce same result in the limit, and simplify.

The asymptotic forms are exact, in the sense that they numerically converge appropriately. For example, for $x\rightarrow 0$ limit, you need both $e^{-1/x}$ and $e^{1/x}$ to approximate correct result, so we indeed need  hyperbolic function:

\begin{align}
f(0.005)=\text{5.53558610694695$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-83}\\
\frac{\text{sech}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{2 x^2}\text{/.}\, x\to 0.005=\text{5.53558610694695$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-83}\\
\exp \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\text{/.}\, x\to 0.005=\text{1.3838965267367376$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-87}
\end{align}

Of course, the limiting result becomes less accurate for higher values:
\begin{align}f(0.1)=0.00453958\\\frac{\text{sech}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{2x^2}\text{/.}\, x\to 0.1=0.00453999\end{align}

Comment: With 11.3 you can check with `AsymptoticEqual[1/x^2 Exp[1/x] (Exp[1/x] + 1)^-2, Sech[1/x]/(2 x^2), 
 x -> 0]` and `AsymptoticEqual[1/x^2 Exp[1/x] (Exp[1/x] + 1)^-2, 1/(4 x^2), 
 x -> Infinity]`.

Comment: Tricky application of a new function `AsymptoticEqual` which I didn't know(MMA  11.0.1)! One question remains looking at `Simplify[ ExpToTrig[f[x]] ] (*Sech[1/(2 x)]^2/(4 x^2) *)`: Is there any advantage to approximate f[x] with a similar function `(*Sech[1/( x)]/(2 x^2) *)`?

Comment: An approximation should be of simple form.  The function `E^(-1/x)/x^2 ` is more simple, but yields the same good approximation than `Sech[1/x]/(2 x^2) `. See  `E^(-1/x)/x^2 /. x -> .005 ` gives also `5.53559*10^-83 ` and `E^(-1/x)/x^2 /. x -> .1 ` gives also `0.00453999 ` . `Sech[1/x]/(2 x^2) // TrigToExp // Simplify // ExpandAll ` is equal `E^(1/x)/(x^2 + E^(2/x) x^2) ` . The first x^2 in the denominator can totaly be negelected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis of the low limit function approximation.
@UlrichNeumann I think we have to rely on our analytical skills in subtle cases.

Answer (score 0):

Get a simple graphical solution.

Expand all terms of the function and regard, which summand of the denominator is dominating the behavior of `f[x]` approaching zero.

```
f[x_] = 1/x^2 Exp[1/x] (Exp[1/x] + 1)^-2 // ExpandAll

(*    E^(1/x)/(x^2 + 2 E^(1/x) x^2 + E^(2/x) x^2)   *)

Table[n[i] = Numerator[f[x]]/Denominator[f[x]][[i]], {i, 3}] // Simplify

(*   {E^(1/x)/x^2, 1/(2 x^2), E^(-1/x)/x^2}   *)

Plot[{f[x], n[1], n[2], n[3]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Magenta, Blue}]
```

[image]

You see, `E^(-1/x)/x^2` is the best approximation. It yields the same good approximation like `Sech[1/x]/(2 x^2)` , but is more simple. (See my comment to the answer of @Soner)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is as follows.

```
Normal[Series[1/T^2*Exp[1/T]*(Exp[1/T] + 1)^(-2), {T, Infinity, 3}]]
```

> 1/(4 T^2)

```
Normal[Series[1/T^2*Exp[1/T]*(Exp[1/T] + 1)^(-2), {T, 0, 1}]]
```

> E^(1/T)/((1 + E^(1/T))^2 T^2)

Addition. Here is a minor improvement of the Soner's answer.

```
limiterFA = Function[{input, variable, limit},FullSimplify[
TrigToExp[Simplify[Normal[FullSimplify[input SeriesData[variable, limit, 
List[1], 0, 1, 1]]]]] //. 
 Plus[a_, b_] :>  /; AsymptoticEqual[a + b, a, variable -> limit, 
    Direction -> "FromAbove"]]];
f[x_] := 1/x^2 Exp[1/x] (Exp[1/x] + 1)^-2;limiterFA[f[x], x, 0]
```

> E^(-1/x)/x^2

Comment: Your approximation to the function in 0 T limit yields the function itself!

Comment: @Chandan Sharma: This is caused by the different behavior of Exp[1/T] at $T=0$ from the right and from the left.